# Redhat Openshift with AWS (ROSA) Cluster creation using terraform

Tags: redhat

I need to create Redhat Openshift with AWS (ROSA) Cluster using terraform. Can someone let me know about sample scripts or modules if available?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to install the rosa cli and use the local-exec provisioner to run the cli installer.

```
resource "null_resource" "rosa_provisioner" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = rosa create cluster $ARGS_LIST
  }
  environment = {
    ARGS_LIST = "--cluster-name=cluster --sts --mode=auto" 
  }
}
```

If you need to accept variable arg inputs it gets harder because of how the rosa cli is structured. Be happy to share a couple examples if you need it.

Comment: We don't have official terraform module till yet?